# How to convert Date data type from oracle ( format " 01-JAN-19") in LocalDate data type in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, localdate

I try to convert using LocalDate.parse() and dont work. In database all Date are format "01-JAN-19" (dd-mm-yy).

```
LocalDate.parse(resultSet.getString(5))
```

Comment: What data type has the column in Oracle? If it is a `date` is has no intrinsic format. That's a misconception of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `ResultSet.getString` for a date. Since [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) get a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) at once:

```
resultSet.getObject(5, LocalDate.class)
```

Note the use of [`getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int)) rather than `getString` or `getDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I know nothing about Oracle and how they handle dates, so there may be a better answer.

---

Assuming that you want to create a `LocalDate` object from a `String`, such as `"01-JAN-19"`, you'll have to use a [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) and invoke [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseCaseInsensitive`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive()) (because the month in your example is uppercase):

```
var formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy").toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("01-JAN-19", formatter));
```

Output:

```
2019-01-01
```

`LocalDate#parse` didn't work for you because you specified `mm` (which refers to *minutes* instead of *months*), as well as it attempting to parse case-sensitive by default.